# _thetextblock.Text is null on slider minimum set as 5 not 0?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, null, textblock

I have databinding setup on a slider and the databinding sets the slider to 5.
I also set the minimum slider value as 5 using the properties in the xaml, yet it fails to compile and highlights `_masterSpeedTxt.Text = line` as the problem. 
If I hover over the `_masterSpeedTxt.Text`  it pops up null and if I press the `+` and again on static members everything returns null.
Yet if I set the slider at minimum 0 again it all works fine.

I'm new to programming and to me this makes no sense what so ever could it be a bug in VS Express 2012?

I've seen this but thats databinded to the slider value yet I want to convert into a percentage...

[Problems with WP8 Slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17076134/problems-with-wp8-slider)

```
private void _masterSpeedSlider_ValueChanged(object sender,   RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        double slVal = Math.Round(((Slider)sender).Value);
        //int total = 255;
        double percentage = (slVal * 500) / 250;

        _masterSpeedTxt.Text = String.Format("{0}%", Convert.ToString(percentage));

        string sendMI = Convert.ToString(Math.Round(((Slider)sender).Value));

        sendMI.PadLeft(3, '0');

        string fsSend = sendMI.PadLeft(3, '0');
        SocketConnect.sendtoFS(String.Format("FSOC206{0}", fsSend));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding it to :

```
       // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _masterSpeedSlider.Minimum = 5;
    }
```

Solved the problem!